# How to correctly modify an existed column to auto increment from a set number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table created in mySQL that i have already created and i want to alter one of the columns in the table to auto increment starting at 39 (because i already have 38 entries).

Originally the column i was trying to edit wasn't set as a primary key so i did that by:

```
ALTER TABLE expenses ADD PRIMARY KEY (Expense_No);
```

the action output returned a green tick for that so i'm assuming that column was successfully set as the primary key?

and now I am trying to get that column to auto increment by using:

```
ALTER TABLE expenses MODIFY COLUMN Expense_No INT AUTO_INCREMENT = 39;
```

but I am getting a syntax error under the INT of "unexpected 'INT' (int)" and another under the = of "unexpected '=' (equal operator )".

quite confused and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Try: `ALTER TABLE expenses AUTO_INCREMENT = 39;`

Comment: thanks for the reply @wchiquito, I did that and at first i thought it worked, then i tried to enter an entry to the table and it gave it the primary Key expense No of 0, and then i tried to enter another and it gave an erry as duplicate entry 0 for key primary

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table involved?

Answer (score 0):

To get the result what you want, you first tell what the new AUTO_INCREMENT value should be and then modify the column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE expenses AUTO_INCREMENT = 39, MODIFY COLUMN Expense_No INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I have typed this in but i am still getting a syntax error under the int of of "unexpected 'INT' (int)"

Comment: @ayoolaadedeji Are you sure it is an INT column? What if you drop the primary key on your table and use this command: ALTER TABLE expenses AUTO_INCREMENT = 39, MODIFY COLUMN Expense_No INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;